# Reverse proxy with nginx on Ubuntu 20.04, does not work on old devices

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, reverse-proxy

I had a Debian 9.3 server, with a nginx reverse proxy. I decided to migrate to Ubuntu 20.04, installed nginx, and HTTPS does not work at all on an old device that runs **windows ce 6.1**.

Out of curiosity I decided to install Debian again, and install nginx and configure the reverse proxy, and HTTPS returned to work on the old device. The version of nginx that I was having problems with on Ubuntu is **1.18**, which is the same version that I installed on Debian.

The error that the old mobile device returns when accessing the application in Ubuntu is: **undefined path or network problem.**

How can I solve this problem?

Does the nginx reverse proxy on Ubuntu need any specific header or configuration?

Comment: It's probably an old weak SSL cipher that is no longer supported. The useful life of your old Windows CE device is soon coming to an end.

Comment: For me, it came to an end a long time ago. We will start switching soon, it worked on everything except Windows CE 6.1. Anyway, we'll see what to do here.